# Updating a python Tkinter frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having difficulty updating a python Tkinter frame.  I draw the frame with
some labels and text fields, when a person presses a button, I want to do some
calculations and update the labels and text fields.  I can print the data to my
stdout, but I cannot get the Tk screen to update.  How can I get the countFld to display an updated value?

```
class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
      self.root = Tk()
      Frame.__init__(self, self.root)
      self.count = 0
      self.createWidgets()

  def createWidgets(self):
      self.countFrame = Frame(self, bd=2, relief=RIDGE)
      Label(self.countFrame, text='Count:').pack(side=LEFT, padx=5)
      self.countFld = IntVar()
      Label(self.countFrame, text=str(self.count)).pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5)
      self.countFld.set(self.count)
      self.countFrame.pack(expand=1, fill=X, pady=10, padx=5)

      self.CNTBTN = Button(self)
      self.CNTBTN["text"] = "UPDATE"
      self.CNTBTN["fg"]   = "red"
      self.CNTBTN["command"] =  self.update_count 
      self.CNTBTN.pack({"side": "left"})

  def update_count(self):
      self.count = self.count + 1
      print "Count = %" % self.count #prints correct value
      self.countFld.set(self.count)  #Does not update display
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you do not attach the Variable to the widget. In addition you need to use a StringVar, as the Label Widget operates on Strings and not Ints.

Try something like:

```
self.countStr = StringVar()
self.countStr.set(str(self.count))
Label(self.countFrame, textvariable=self.countStr).pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5)
```

Tk updates the display when the eventloop is idle. So you need to re-enter the event loop after you set the new value.

Answer (score 1):

You should try destroying the label itself and making it again in the code with the updated text and use self.root.update()